# Messenger m.me parameter not received on webhook

Tags: facebook-messenger

I'm trying to pass parameter via m.me link but for some reason it doesn't work.  The webhook I get from the server doesn't contains the "referral" field.

I tried to re-subscribe to the web hook but it didn't help.
A video with the full flow of sending the parameters and the webhook response - http://g.recordit.co/XShDj1Rx29.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that if the page is unpublished the referral field parameters are not passed in the webhook.

Publishing the page solved the problem